# Why can't I overload the * operator to multiply rectangles with 2D vectors?

Tags: c#, xna

I was trying to overload the multiplication operator for convenience of scaling 2D sprites, but it seems like one of the operands has to be of a containing type. This is a pity cause I don't find my solution illogical. Also, I found out that such operator overloads should be declared within the class declaration of one of the operands. So, do I have to create my own custom SuperRectangle class or there are some workarounds?

```
public static Rectangle operator * (Rectangle rect, Vector2 scale)
{
    return new Rectangle(rect.X, rect.Y, (int)(rect.Width * scale.X), (int)(rect.Height * scale.Y));
}
```

Comment: It avoids some "WTF?" questions w.r.t C++ operators ;-)

Comment: I don't know if you've looked at this site but it might help spark some ideas on how to get your * overriding working (even though the example is for equals) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: We have considered adding the feature you desire -- essentially "extension operators" -- to C# but it's never made it high enough on the priority list.

Answer (score 5):

You can overload `*` if one or more of the types is user-defined and the overload definition is contained within one of the types involved. If the types involved are built-in and/or you do not control the source code, you will not be able to define your own overload. (See: Sections 7.3 and 7.3.2 of the [C# Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx))

Generally speaking, you could convert your logic to extension methods on `Rectangle` and/or `Vector2` and still accomplish your overall goal.

```
public static class RectangleExtensions 
{
    public static Rectangle MultiplyBy(this Rectangle rect, Vector2 scale)
    {
        return new Rectangle(//...
    }

    public static Rectangle MultiplyBy(this Vector2 scale, Rectangle rect) 
    {
        return new Rectangle(//...
    }
}

// using it
Rectangle output = yourRect.MultiplyBy(yourVector);
```

Comment: I agree with the use of an extension method. It might be clearer to call it "ScaleBy" instead of "MultiplyBy" to make it a little bit more obvious that only the Width/Height are getting multiplied by the vector.